# Python-take the first values according to a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe below. After selecting a list of values that 'Status'=0, I would like to select the first values in this list. How can I do that?

Here is my code but it has an error. In this example, the output must be 6

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data =pd.DataFrame({
'TruckName':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
'Status':[1,1,1,1,1,0],
'ArrivalTime':[1,2,3,4,5,6],

 })
data

a=data.loc[(data['Status']==0),'ArrivalTime'][1]
```

Comment: Use `.head(1)` to select the first row of a df/series.

Comment: `a = data.loc[(data['Status']==0), 'ArrivalTime'].head(1)`